# .NET 4.7 NuGet package files not being packed to correct directory

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-4.7.2

I'm currently trying to create a NuGet package for my .NET 4.7 project. I've previously done this for a .NET 7 project without issue, but in my .NET 4.7 project, my *.dll files are being packaged into a different folder than I've specified.

This is my current ItemGroup setup:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\..\ressources\Detectia.png">
        <Pack>True</Pack>
        <PackagePath></PackagePath>
        <Link>Detectia.png</Link>
    </None>
    <Content Include="tessdata\**" Pack="true" PackagePath="tessdata" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest">
        <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="$(NuGetPackageRoot)tesseract\5.2.0\x64\*.dll" Pack="true" PackageCopyToOutput="true" PackagePath="lib/net47/x64">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <None Include="$(NuGetPackageRoot)tesseract\5.2.0\x86\*.dll" Pack="true" PackageCopyToOutput="true" PackagePath="lib/net47/x86">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <Content Include="DETECTIA.ContentSearch47.targets" Pack="true" PackageCopyToOutput="true" PackagePath="build/">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

When I pack and check the resulting NUPKG, I find that the files I need are copied to a content folder, but without any subfolders (i.e., x64 and x86). Essentially, they're in the wrong path and there are no subfolders.

My targets file also gets copied to the content folder. What I'm expecting is for my DLL files to be copied to lib/net47/, and from there either to x64 or x86.

I also receive these warnings:

> WARNING: NU5100: The assembly 'content\leptonica-1.82.0.dll' is not inside the 'lib' folder and hence it won't be added as a reference when the package is installed into a project. Move it into the 'lib' folder if it needs to be referenced.
> WARNING: NU5100: The assembly 'content\tesseract50.dll' is not inside the 'lib' folder and hence it won't be added as a reference when the package is installed into a project. Move it into the 'lib' folder if it needs to be referenced.

What have i missed?